# c# app: Is it possible to implement a JSON interface?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web-services, json

I've built a simple C# app (.Net 4.0 + WPF) which can send and receive JSON messages via TCP sockets.

As a next step, it should be possible that JavaScript apps on websites and PHP scripts can send and receive JSON messages to/from my app. Is that possible?

Since JS/PHP will use stateless HTTP connections, how should a request to my app work, for example, should the JS/PHP apps send a JSON message to my app and my app response (HTTP response) with a JSON message? Is that even possible? And should I use GET or POST method to send the JSON messages to/from my app?

Hope my questions do not cause too much confusion ;-) I but I appreciate every tip, clarification or feedback you can give me.

Mike

Comment: Why would a WPF (fat-client) app of yours act as a host for JSON messages?  That does not sound like a very robust server solution.

Comment: @Kirk Woll It's a peer-to-peer app, so there will be no central host/server

Comment: Ah, so you expect all your users to poke a hole in their firewall?

Comment: Every p2p-network has this problem. If only every 20th client will open the door, I think it should be enough (but I have no experience). I mean, hey, if you open the JSON port you will earn the "P2P King Badge" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this via a .NET web service using special JSON directives on the web method, e.g.

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string DoSomething(string param1, int param2) 
{
   // Do Something
}
```

When the `ResponseFormat.Json` property is specified, the data returned will be serialized into the appropriate JSON format.  Also note, in order to recieve a true JSON response, you'll need to set your content-type to `"application/json"` from the requesting application.  Otherwise, the method will attempt to wrap the response in XML.

Also, I am enabling a HttpGet on this method so that you can post via a query string to the method, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/service.asmx?param1='Hello'&param2=1;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your quick answer! I've two questions in regard to your example: 1. Since my app is a "normal" WPF app, is it a problem if it has only an IP/Port, for example: http: //156.25.365.25:4500/service.asmx?param1='Hello'&param2=1;[/code] ?

Comment: @Mike, that will not cause a problem.  (though I assume you have accounted for your users' firewalls?)

Comment: Second question: Since you are using "UseHttpGet = true", does this mean, the JS/PHP apps have to send JSON messages to my app always with the GET method?

Comment: @George Since I want to host the JSON interface (web service) in a WPF app, it seems that I'm not able to use .asmx "The traditional ASMX Web services were hosted only on Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS)." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx